# block and wakeup consumer threads/

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 2 threads.

each of them reads some data from a shared buffer.

```
currentDataBuffer.get(thisID); //currentDataBuffer is my shared buffer object
```

I want to block every thread after every call to get , and release it when all thread read the buffer (once)
so I used this `currentDataBuffer` object as lock:

```
currentDataBuffer.get(thisID);
synchronized (currentDataBuffer ) {
   currentDataBuffer.wait();
}
```

The problem is how can I release those threads when all threads finished reading from buffer (one line each)?

inside `currentDataBuffer` I have a map where I store the ids of threads that read data from buffer.

how can I use `this.notifyAll();` (from `currentDataBuffer` ) to wake up all locked threads?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the Java [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) data structure. Calling `BlockingQueue.take()` blocks until an element is available.
So instead of:

```
currentDataBuffer.get(thisID);
synchronized (currentDataBuffer ) {
   currentDataBuffer.wait();
}
```

You will have:

```
currentDataBuffer.take();
```

The thread blocked on the `take()` call can be released by adding an element to the queue by calling the `BlockingQueue.offer(object)` method

Comment: I need one buffer for n-threads, only AFTER all threads read SAME data i need to move to next item in buffer.

Answer (score 0):

An answer that continues your code might be to use `currentDataBuffer.notifyAll()` instead of `this.notifyAll()` (it not so clear what `this` refers to from your question). But then how would you insure that the call to `notifyAll` happens after all threads have read the buffer and entered the wait state?

If you know the number of threads that should read the buffer, a better solution would be to use two [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). There's a good example in that class's javadoc.

------------ UPDATE:

You don't need to change the reader threads' code. You should hold the latches in your `currentDataBuffer` object. Create a thread in `currentDataBuffer` that waits on `n` items latch. In the `get` method, call `CountDownLatch.countDown()` on that latch after the reading is finished. Oh, I'll write it:

```
class CurrentDataBuffer implements Runnable {

    private CountDownLatch singleThreadFinishedSignal;
    private CountDownLatch allThreadsFinishedSignal;

    public CurrentDataBuffer(int N) {
        singleThreadFinishedSignal = new CountDownLatch(N); // waiter thread waits on this
        allThreadsFinishedSignal = new CountDownLatch(1); // reader threads wait on this after finished reading
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            singleThreadFinishedSignal.await(); // wait for all reader threads to finish
            allThreadsFinishedSignal.countDown(); // let all reader threads proceed
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void get() {
        try {
            // read buffer item here ///////////////////
            singleThreadFinishedSignal.countDown(); // mark that a thread has read the item
            allThreadsFinishedSignal.await(); // wait for other reader threads to finish
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes I know the number of threads. I use this.notifyAll() within the currentDataBuffer  object itself, this why it "this".

Comment: I can't use CountDownLatch because I can't alter (the code)the creation of the threads

Comment: I don't get, how does it know what threads use it?! I don't have to specify anything on consumer-thread part??

Comment: I've called get from the consumer threads (above the currentDataBuffer.get(thisID) line). both thread stopped there.

Comment: If you know in advance the number of threads, then you can just expose a getter (as in the example) that forces the consumers that invoke it to wait until other `get` N invocations are executed.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment (both thread stopped etc.). If you'll show the code it might be helpful.

Comment: I mean after I call your Get() within my threads, bot of them block on this line, currentDataBuffer.get()

Comment: I want to clarify currentDataBuffer object is shared by 2 consumers threads that read data and a producer thread that adds data to it. I can't control the start of any of the threads

Comment: What's `currentDataBuffer` type?

Answer (score 0):

I think a CountdownLatch ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html ) would help.

I.e. augment your currentDataBuffer with a CountDownLatch with initial value of 2 (or whatever number of threads you want to process). After processing the thread calls latch.countDown() and then latch.await().

For safety you probably want to be careful that countDowns cannot get lost (e.g. if an exception is thrown).

Comment: I can't use CountDownLatch because I can't alter (the code)the creation of the threads

Comment: Do you have control over the class for the currentDataBuffer? If so you could add the countDown()/await() in its get method.

Comment: yes, I have control of currentDataBuffer, but why should i put wait there? consumers threads are those that read data from buffer!

Comment: if I put wait in get() after first thread tries to read data, no other thread would ever  awake it